# Raising an existing concrete floor

Tags: flooring

I have a sunroom with ceramic floor tile over a concrete slab.  I have two steps down which are not to code. One is 9 inches deep and the second is 10 inches deep to the floor.  I would need to raise the existing floor by three inches and one step by one inch to give me the 8 inch drop.  Do I need to remove the tile and then build up the existing floor with a self leveling concrete to have a smooth surface?  I was not intending to put new tile down but would like a concrete stain.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work for almost no benefit if you're not being forced to do the work by the code enforcement folks.

Comment: Can you add a 3rd step and just make them all ~6" risers?

Answer (score 3):

Too new to comment, so I apologize in advance for this being a fairly rotten answer, but 3 treads, about 6-1/2" rise, 11" -13" run would solve your code problem.

Comment: Perfectly reasonable answer, and should be far less hassle (not to mention expense) than raising the whole floor.